# Sort by association of association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Order belongs_to :delivery_timeslot
DeliveryTimeslot has_many :orders
DeliveryTimeslot belongs_to :timeslot
Timeslot has_many :delivery_timeslots
```

I want to sort by id of timeslots:

```
Order.includes(delivery_timeslot: :timeslot).order('orders.delivery_timeslot.timeslot.id')
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: just `Order.includes(delivery_timeslot: :timeslot).order('timeslot.id')` does not work?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
Order.includes(delivery_timeslot: :timeslot).order('timeslots.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense in SQL something like that. You have to specify just the table (optional, if it's not an ambiguous column) and the column. Try

```
Order.includes(delivery_timeslot: :timeslot).order('timeslots.id')
```